# How do I redirect a URL with dashes to a URL with only specific keywords from string

Tags: regex, nginx

Trying to redirect

/currency/bitcoin-btc to

/currency/bitcoin

Using htaccess rewrite rules

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^currency/(.*)[a-z-](.*)$ /currency/$1 [R=301,L
```

How do I strip the second keyword after the dash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
RewriteRule ^(currency/.*)-.* /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This way, `currency/` substring at the start and all 0 or more chars up to the last `-` will get captured into `$1`, and the last `-` with any 0+ chars after it will get dropped.